# How to retrieve dataLayer Object using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-datalayer

I'm trying to find a way to extract the datalayer object from a website via java, using selenium webdriver.
I am using the jsExecutor.executeScript to pass the "windows.dataLayer" command to the Chrome Console Tab and parse the data to ArrayList. However whenever I run my code it consistently fails and spits out following:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: backendNodeId is missing in a node

Things I have tried:

- various substitutes for javascript command:

  - "return dataLayer;"
  - "return JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer);"
  - "return console.log('dataLayer')";
- Restarting the Computer
- Killing all instance of ChromeDriver from cmd through Taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T

Selenium v4.8.3
ChromeDriver v116

**My Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
        // Get the website.
        driver.get("https://mvnrepository.com/");
    
        // Create a WebDriverWait object.
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    
        // Wait for the page to finish loading.
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.readyState === 'complete';"));
    
        // Wait for the dataLayer object to become present.
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return (typeof dataLayer !== 'undefined');"));
    
        // Wait for the dataLayer object to be an object.
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return (typeof dataLayer === 'object');"));
    
        // Get the JavascriptExecutor object.
        JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    
        // Try to retrieve the dataLayer object.
        try {
            ArrayList<String> dataLayer = (ArrayList<String>) jsExecutor.executeScript("return window.dataLayer;");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exception.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        // Print the dataLayer object.
        System.out.println(dataLayer);
    
        // Quit the driver.
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unkown error: backendNodeId is missing in a node 
    at Example.Main (Example.java: 19) --\>  ArrayList\<String\> dataLayer = (ArrayList\<String\>) jsExecutor.executeScript("return dataLayer;");
```

Comment: seems like that type-cast is confusing the driver. (??) I'd remove that and see if it helps.  This seems like a bug in either Chrome or Chromedriver, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it's neither, i have tried removing casting and switched to an older version of chrome & chrome driver but it still spits the same error. 
For more information: I used the above code for some lower environment testing and it worked but when i tried it against prod env it spits that error out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Object" then apply your process.

```
Object dataLayer = jsExecutor.executeScript("return window.dataLayer;");

if (dataLayer instanceof List<?>) {
   List<?> dataLayerList = (List<?>) dataLayer;
   if (dataLayerList.size() > 0) {
      dataLayers.add(dataLayerList);
   }
}
```